# Calling python with dynamic parameters from PowerShell v1.0

Tags: python, variables, powershell, command, invoke

I'm building out a powershell script that does quite a bit of work extracting csv's from a zip, converting OS->lat/lon, stuffing the contents robustly into a DB, and then emailing a distribution list with stats on the whole process.

Most of this is now complete, but to make the whole thing a little more portable I'm providing paths to input/working/output folders as parameters of the powershell call from a batch file.

This is all working fantatstically until I need to call python scripts to do the lat/lon work, as passing in the variable parameter paths doesn't seem to work with any permutation/combination.

The following is a simplified version of the python path within the .PS1 script which works from both command prompt and from within the .PS1 file if called directly (*where -i -o are input/output path parameters*).

```
c:\python27\python.exe D:\PythonPPC\subs.py -i D:\PPC\subs_export.csv -o D:\PPC\subs_export_lat_lon.csv
```

In my script I would like to replace the two path parameters -i/-o with variables something like:

```
c:\python27\python.exe D:\PythonPPC\subs.py -i $inputPathsubs_export.csv -o $outputPathsubs_export_lat_lon.csv
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to invoke this command as I've tried the &$exe method described on stack and a few other places, but this simply results in the error shown below:

```
CommandNotFoundException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the `Join-Path` cmdlet for building paths. It will save you the headache of keeping track of leading/trailing path separators and also canonicalize `/` to `\`.

```
$workingFolder = 'C:\some/where\'
$extractFolder = '\extract\folder'
$infileName    = '/subs_export.csv'
$outfileName   = '\subs_export_lat_lon.csv'

$infile  = Join-Path (Join-Path $workingFolder $extractFolder) $infileName
$outfile = Join-Path (Join-Path $workingFolder $extractFolder) $outfileName
```

Result:

```
PS C:\> $infile
C:\some\where\extract\folder\subs_export.csv
PS C:\> $outfile
C:\some\where\extract\folder\subs_export_lat_lon.csv
```

If you still want to simply concatenate strings to a path, you can separate variables from trailing strings by putting the variable name between curly brackets. In your example:

```
python.exe D:\PythonPPC\subs.py -i "${inputPath}subs_export.csv" ...
```

or

```
python.exe D:\PythonPPC\subs.py -i "${rootFolder}${subFolder}subs_export.csv" ...
```

Comment: Cheers for the comment @Ansgar. The script has been getting quite messy with paths concatenated all over the place so I may go back and use this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After attacking the problem from a different direction and a colleague pointing out my own abject stupidity, it seems the following is a fairly straightforward solution to the complicated problem above.

```
$inputFilePath = $pathToWorkingFolder + $pathToExtractFolder + 'subs_export.csv'
$outputFilePath = $pathToWorkingFolder + $pathToExtractFolder +'subs_export_lat_lon.csv'    
c:\python27\python.exe D:\PythonPPC\subs.py -i $inputFilePath -o $outputFilePath
```

Just needed some peer review I guess...

Comment: Didn't see the context of the script. But one problem I can see is that the `$inputPathsubs_export.csv` will be taken as a variable with name "$inputPathsubs_export.csv" which doesn't exist at all. You might add one back slash to make it `$inputPath\subs_export.csv`.

Comment: Use the `Join-Path` cmdlet to create your paths. Don't concatenate by hand.